# why do I get the needing a string but bytes found error however I try to write to a file or vairable in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3
Ok I'm probably having a senior moment but this should not be generating an error...very simple code. Isn't even letting me set text to a variable. What gives?

```
f = open('/usr/local/tdproxy/USERIMP/TESTFILES/triggersearch.txt','w')
   test = "test code"
   f.write(test)
   f.close()
```

and the error

```
test = "test code"
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: That's odd - this code works correctly on my machine using Arch Linux, I just modified the filename to something that exists on my system.

Comment: agreed..it is a head shaker here...

Comment: This should raise an IndentationError.

Comment: @mkrieger1 just a weird copy and paste.....it is intented correctly

Comment: There is an option to [edit] your question to show the code as it is supposed to look, without weird copy and paste.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is on the line `test = "test code"` and not on the line `f.write(test)`?

Comment: @VelizarHristov hello all.. so inherently the code I was changing was part of an import into another block of code. I had to restart the FLASK server each time.. What was interested is that part of the change worked each time just saving the file and part of the change didn't...so it was a very ofdd FLASK behavior. I was able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use .decode('UTF-8') on the string parts but here was the kicker. If you are using FLASK you have to restart the flask every time you make a change.

Here is he kicker #2 you only have to restart the flask for certain things..other things would change like what line the error was on without needing to restart the flask..